# Issue with Jenkins and Git submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I am trying to get Jenkins working on a Windows PC and have found a weird issue with submodules.

I have a git repo with three submodules. After a while it seems I got Git itself working on Jenkins so a normal clone works. However the clone does not clone the submodules inside the main repo, so I checked the box to recursively update submodules.

[image]

However, when I run my job:

```
Started by user <User>
Building in workspace X:\Jenkins\<JobName>
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh://git@<server>/<repo>.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from  ssh://git@<server>/<repo>.git
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe fetch --tags --progress  ssh://git@<server>/<repo>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b13204ee1c6717a82d1c7a17922f2a477efd119d (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "testinggg.."
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe checkout -f b13204ee1c6717a82d1c7a17922f2a477efd119d
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe rev-list b13204ee1c6717a82d1c7a17922f2a477efd119d # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe remote # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule sync # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule init # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp ^submodule\.(.*)\.url # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config --get submodule.top.url # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe remote # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.top.path # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
- C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule update --init --recursive top
FATAL: Command "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule update --init --recursive top" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'top'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe submodule update --init --recursive top" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'top'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$7.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1076)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:102)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1182)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

What does Git mean when it says:

> Needed a single revision Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'top'

I have looked around and found nothing :(

I have replicated this sequence of command on a normal shell and no error appeared.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To anybody getting similar issues, check the box for Jenkins to wipe out the local workspace and force repository clone once. That worked for me ;)

Comment: This is working but much slower. Is there a better fix in the meantime ?

Answer (score 1):

`top` branch sha mismatched to the commited sha for the submodule.

Consider enabling "Update tracking submodules to tip of branch" option.

This may not work for tags though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 'top' is one of your submodules. The main repo that contains submodules just stores a commit ID of each of the submodules as reference to them. I interpret the error message as if there is a commit ID for 'top' in the main repo that cannot be found (does not exist?) in 'top'. I'd check this to be sure about this.

In the last project I worked with Git submodules and Jenkins we didn't use the Git plugin's ***Advanced sub-modules behaviours*** but executed all the `git submodule ...` commands in a *Builder: Execute shell* step of the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin). *Conditional* to be able to abort the build if something goes wrong during these Git commands.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "ID". Indeed "top" is the path where one of my submodules goes. My gitmodules file only lists the repo URL, their branch and their path, not commit information is included. Is that normal?

Comment: @viterbi By "ID" I mean the 20-byte-hash that's assigned to every commit. Yes, [that's normal](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) but I wasn't referring to that. See [git-submodule](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule): "_Submodules are composed from a so-called gitlink tree entry in the main repository that refers to a particular commit object within the inner repository that is completely separate. A record in the .gitmodules (...) file at the root of the source tree assigns a logical name to the submodule and describes the default URL the submodule shall be cloned from._"

Comment: I really don't know what I am doing wrong. If I clone the repo with the submodules recursively I have no issues, when jenkins does it, the "Needed single revision" message appears... I really want to avoid doing this manually, if jenkins is suposed to be able to handle I much prefer to have him do it...

Comment: @viterbi I don't know either. Jenkins and its plugins are software. No SW is 100 % error-free. If you don't even consider to try the workaround I suggested I'm outta here.

Comment: Ok it looks like I fixed it. I just told jenkins to wipe out repository to force reclone once and it started working. I did not think of that, I guess there were some files there provoking errors. To anybody having troubles with Jenkins Git, make jenkins wipe out the repo until you have the task all set-up! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Even though, our workspace gets cleaned. We still aren't getting the latest master from our submodule in Jenkins. Locally it works fine.